# Method Overloading with varargs

Tags: java, int, byte, variadic-functions, short

I am a bit confused about this topic, reason being in this code:

```
public class File
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        numbers();
    }

    static void numbers(int...x)
    {
        System.out.println("Integers");
    }
    static void numbers(byte...x)
    {
        System.out.println("Byte");
    }
    static void numbers(short...x)
    {
        System.out.println("Short");
    }
}
```

The output of this code is "Byte", and the reason is the most specific type is chosen, since among `byte`, `short` and `int` the most specific type is `byte`, that's why it is chosen.

But if I modify my code to-

```
public class File
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        numbers(1, 4);
    }

    static void numbers(int...x)
    {
        System.out.println("Integers");
    }
    static void numbers(byte...x)
    {
        System.out.println("Byte");
    }
    static void numbers(short...x)
    {
        System.out.println("Short");
    }
}
```

The output is "Integers", and I'm unable to figure out why? I know in case of arithmetic instructions `byte` and `short` are implicitly promoted to `int`, but here we are calling a method with values which is within the range of `byte` and `short`, then how the method with `int` arguments is invoked?

And also, if I comment out the method with `int` arguments, then the code shows an error of no suitable method found. Why???

Answer (score 4):

`1` and `4` are integer literals. So the `int...` version is called.

There are no `byte` or `short` literals, but if you were to call `Numbers((byte)2, (byte)3);` the `byte...` version would be called.

Comment: The fact that `Numbers()` is not reported as ambiguous where it clearly should still scares me

Comment: @Clashsoft But it's not ambiguous. There are clear rules that apply. A different thing entirely is whether it's a good idea to have overloads with primitive values like that, but that's the programmer's fault.

Comment: "You can give me a `byte`, a `short` or an `int`. You give me nothing. That means you gave me a `byte`."